# can you help me fix this floating submenu

Tags: html, css

Here's link to the code  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrf4jxpy/1/)

The problem is when mouse over the `<ul>` in "service & support" , the `<li>` below it didn't go down,

Can someone help me fix it????

thanks

Comment: Do you maybe have a sketch of what you would like it to be? Or a little bit more info what the goal is here?

Comment: @TomKriek: Check the fiddle. If the menu is dropped and you hover over the "+" the menu should expand to get some space for the extra content.

Comment: like http://rmc.net84.net submenu when browser width < 900px

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in the question. If your link dies or jsFiddle goes down this question becomes useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrf4jxpy/3/).

Some alterations in the css of:

```
#menu li {
        height:auto;
        float:none;
        clear:both;
        width:89%;
        min-height:60px;
    height:auto;
        margin-left:5.5%;
        border-bottom:thin solid #f8aa5a;
        padding-bottom:15px;
```

---

This includes the use of `height: auto;`
as well as using `padding` instead of `margins`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxtvaae3/) based on your jsFiddle.

I made some change in jquery and css.

Added in your css.

```
#menu li > ul{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

and made some other changes.

Answer (score 0):

your fault because you put the height of li 53px, and it should be min-height.

```
#menu li {
    border-bottom: thin solid #f8aa5a;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 5.5%;
    min-height: 53px;
    width: 89%;
}

#menu ul{
.
.
.
.
top:2px; //instead of 5..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some code in your jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wayzz/vrf4jxpy/2/

Using `animate()` I have added `margin-bottom` so it looks like the whole `li` is animating down.

You can find comments on where I added or changed the code. :)